# Adobe Acrobat Fillable Text Form Bkg Color

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I'm trying to change the bkg color of my editable text field I'm creating in Acrobat.

I make the text box, right-click into Properties > Appearance > Fill Color pick a color but it doesn't register. I've pressed Return, ESC and nothing works.

Anything that I'm missing?

(Attached a screenshot of the window)[image]